# Получение базы данных другого приложения

Tags: android, база-данных

Помогите, мучаюсь с разделом data/data. Мне нужно взять базу данных из приложения вконтакте (audio.db) с названиями сохраненной музыки :((((( Неужели никак нельзя просто взять информацию, менять мне ничего не надо.

Comment: Если девайс не рутован то у вас не должно быть доступа к `data/data` папке. А вообще получение списка музыки юзера надо делать через API Вконтакта

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, аппарат рутован. Через терминал все работает, а мое приложение - нет. Вконтакте мне нужна сохраненная музыка в кэше

Comment: Ну, может у вас в коде получения файла что-то не то или разрешений в манифесте нет или вы БД получили и не знаете как её открыть? Раскройте детали проблемы - что именно не работает и что пробовали.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, разрешения ROOT_ACCESS и ACCESS_SUPERUSER  в манифесте прописаны, лог: /data/data/com.vkmp3mod.android/databases/audio.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрашивайте su в рантайме, насколько знаю, в манифесте в относительно свежих версиях андроида эти разрешения бесполезны

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы видите в логах незнакомую ошибку то надо:

1. Скопировать ту её часть, где нет специфических слов (типа пути к вашему конкретному файлу), в вашем случае - `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
2. Вбить её в гугл и перети по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9907574/3212712)
3. Там и ответ - у вас нет разрешения на чтение файлов с устройства. Т.е. надо добавить в манифест:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```

По той же ссылке есть упоминание также того, что некоторые разрешения с API>=23 (Android 6+) надо запрашивать в рантайме. Код как это сделать также есть по ссылке.

Comment: у меня андроид 5, разрешения есть, выставлены, есть на экране установки. И не учите гуглить :D я это сделал сразу ничего путного не нашел, у меня так же как и по этим советам

Comment: @СергейГрушин, ну... Может в коде где-то ошибка. Но вы упрямо отказываетесь раскрывать детали проблемы.